# How can I convert a jar file and a dat file to exe file

Tags: java, jar, filereader, filewriter

I have a jar file and a dat file for my java program. This is a simple typing game and when a player plays the game, the game saves the top scores in that dat file and shows the score.

But I want to convert them both to a single exe file. How can I do that?

The dat file is out of my jar file because my program needs BOTH to write and read the dat file to update and show the top scores AND that is probably not possible keeping the dat file inside the jar file. (I searched this site for this kind of question but I found that it's only possible to read the dat file which is inside the jar file; BUT not to write it.)

Comment: May be you can research [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, an application doesn't manipulate its own executable file while running. This is independent of the executable format (JAR or EXE). Maybe some malicious code is doing such thing, but you don't want your (or your customer's) anti virus program think your application is malware, don't you?

So the common accepted pattern is to seperate program code, master data (read-only) and user data (read-write). You can put the program code and parts or all of the master data (e.g. progam icons, default values, etc.) together to form the executable file. But the user data should be in a seperate file (or database or system registry, etc.).

I don't know why you want to store your user data inside the executable, but if your motivation is that you want to deploy your application as a single file only, then you can use something like [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) to create a setup for your application. Or you put the read-only part of your data file inside the executable so that you don't need to ship an additional data file along your executable. The data file with the user specific data can then be created during the first run.

Comment: Actually I was looking for something like IzPack; but i didn't know about it. Thank u very much.